# How to enable "Rename symbol's file" by default in Visual Studio 2022?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2022

In Visual Studio 2022, when trying to refactor a C# class you are prompted whether or not you also want to "Rename symbol's file." You must now manually enable this feature each time you restart the IDE, but it used to be the feature was enabled by default. Does anyone know how to enable this by default even after restarting the IDE?

[image]

I tried searching the options menu, Microsoft docs, and Stack Overflow, but have found no trace of enabling this feature be default.

Answer (score 0):

I just looked at the most recent update for Visual Studio 2022 and they updated the rename tool. When I used it, the default for me was "Rename Symbol's file" was checked for me. I did not see a way to set or unset it as a default but once you get the update it may now be defaulted.

I have a related question about why someone would not want to do this here ([Visual Studio Inline Rename feature, is there a good reason not to also rename symbol files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75221859/visual-studio-inline-rename-feature-is-there-a-good-reason-not-to-also-rename-s))