# Visual Studio Inline Rename feature, is there a good reason not to also rename symbol files?

Tags: c#, rename, visual-studio-2022

Going through the new features introduced with the latest Visual Studio they included an update to the Rename tool. There is the option to include; comments, strings, and symbol files. I understand why one may not want to rename comments and strings but can not think of a use case for not including symbol files, can someone give me a good reason not to include them?

While I have been developing for a number of years, there are areas I am woefully lacking in understanding, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't rename "symbol files", it asks to rename the "symbol's file", "symbol" being a type name.

C# doesn't necessarily have the "one type per file" dogma. You can group related classes, records, structs in one file.

You could for example have a file `Orders.cs`, containing the symbols `Order`, `OrderLine` and `OrderAddress`. In that case you don't want to rename the file when renaming either symbol.

Comment: Thank you, I was a bit confused by the ‘s that was in the description but note it makes sense.